# subversion merge to grandparent when parent dead

Tags: svn

If I have branch A, then branch off it with B, and then branch off B with C, I want to know what happens if branch B is reintegrated to A before C is reintegrated to B.  So, to clarify what I mean (and your answers):

```
A--r10--r11--r14------r17--r20--r22
    \         \         \   ^ 
     v         v         v /
     B---r13---r15--r18--r19
                \
                 v
                 C--r16---r21
```

If I really don't want to "update" C with A (or B), or resurrect B to allow reintegrate from C to B to A, will a simple merge from C to A work?

```
cd ^/branches/A
svn merge ^/branches/C
```

i.e. will recorded mergeinfo result in svn simply trying to apply r16 and r21 to A, which is what I want (I think)?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684668/svn-create-a-branch-from-branch-and-merge-to-trunk